# Inserting symbols into text in PowerPoint 2007 using VBA

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

I need to append programmatically (VBA/VSTO) several special symbols (e.g., smileys) into text in a `TextRange` in PowerPoint 2007.

I can insert a symbol using:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
    .Text = "sometext"
    Call .Characters(.Characters.Count + 1).InsertSymbol("Arial", 65, MsoTriState.msoTrue)
End With
```

Unfortunately, when I try to insert several symbols one after the other with different fonts, only the last one shows correctly and the previous ones show like empty squares.

How can I insert several symbols from different fonts? Perhaps there is a way to create a new `Run` for each symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `InsertSymbol` erases the contents of the `TextRange`, at least in my tests.

However, I found a way without `InsertSymbol`. Repeat for each symbol:

- `newRun.InsertAfter(character);` //
  insert symbol character, and create a
  new `Run`
- set the "Other" font to the desired
  symbol font - important to use
  `NameOther` and not `Name`, otherwise
  special symbols such as Copyright
- will disappear if they are not
  present in the selected font (e.g.,
  Wingdings does not have the Copyright
  symbol)
- `newRun.get_Characters(newRun.get_Characters(-1, -1).Count, 1).Font.NameOther = symbolFontName;`

Comment: I am working on a hidden window, so I cannot use selections or cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `TextRange` object for each `.InsertSymbol`.

```
Dim tr1 As TextRange
Set tr1 = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
tr1.InsertSymbol "Wingdings", 81
Dim tr2 As TextRange
Set tr2 = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
tr2.InsertSymbol "Wingdings 2", 81
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a lot of time and effort to solve this issue. Then I bothered and posted the solution.

Someone is busy "Voting-Down" my questions/answers without bothering to understand the complexity nor the solutions.