# Strange problem in MS Word VBA. Insert symbol results in empty square

Tags: vba, ms-word

I experience a strange problem in MS Word 2010 VBA. 
I added a ribbon command calling the following code 
    Selection.InsertSymbol Font:="Wingdings 3", CharacterNumber:=-4028, Unicode:=True
After opening Word application for couple of minutes the call to this line 
results in empty squares as if the font was not found. After that all works normally and the symbols are written correctly. Is there any workaround? 
I found similar question here [on SO][1]

[1]: [Inserting symbols into text in PowerPoint 2007 using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025731/inserting-symbols-into-text-in-powerpoint-2007-using-vba/4036098#4036098) but I am not sure that I can use the solution provided there in MS Word.
Maybe there is a way to just preload the Windlings font?

Comment: what symbol is -4028? (you really put a minus in the code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CharacterNumber` is a Variant type, so it should take string values for most things. Just enclose the number in double-quotes. This one works for me:

```
Selection.InsertSymbol Font:="Wingdings 3", CharacterNumber:="-4028", Unicode:=True
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you try the scenario I described in the question? To add a button and connect this code to it?

Comment: I ran the code directly in Word 2010 from the VBE, not from a Ribbon command. But I just added the macro I have the above code in to the QAT and and ran it from there and it works just fine.